# Set up testing of our questionnaire with jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I've worked with jmeter a little before and have just downloaded jmeter 2.7.

Our web application has a questionnaire that each person fills out. Like most questionnaires, the questions that show up vary depending on answers to previous questions, so there are multiple paths and very rarely does one person see all of the questions.

What I'd like to do is create a control file that will specify a group of questionnaires which it will load and log those people into the system and fill out a questionnaire checking the path and results at the end to make sure the answers were stored properly.

I would like to have 25 simultaneous users of this. Eventually I'd like to have a few hundred.

How do I get starting setting all of this up through jmeter? I don't mean a walkthrough, but I'm a little familiar with a number of the jmeter components. Which components would I use to solve this problem and in what order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I recommend upgrading to the latest version of jMeter.

To start every test you should add a thread group(right click on the test plan):

[image]

Then you would specify number of users/threads to 25 by clicking on your thread group and filling in the number of threads field.

Since you're dealing with web you would add a http request to your thread group (I have many more samplers in my screenshot don't get confused, this is because it's possible to extend jmeter with anything you need really) :

[image]

Then after doing some web request you would validate those web requests by using i.e. response assertion :

[image]

I could go on for a long time really. Jmeter documentation is somewhat poor in my opinion but it's a great tool.

Without any specific questions this should be enough to get you started.